# Register command syntax error sql discord.js

Tags: javascript, sql, discord, discord.js

[enter image description here][1]I had a question a couple days ago about how I could add a register command that registers usernames and passwords into the database so that people could login after.

I fixed most of it but now I got this syntax error.

```
bot.on("message", message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (name) VALUES (`${message.content}`)"
        if (command === "register") {
            message.author.send("What username would you like to have?")
            if (message.content = "") 
            con.query(sql, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Expetect ','

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1coD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> con.query(sql, function (err) {
>     if (err) throw err;
> }
> ```

The closing curly bracket `}` is the end of the function declaration. You're missing a closing parenthesis `)` to signify the end of the method parameters.

```js
con.query(sql, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```